# PHP Namespace convention

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-5.3, psr-4

i am not sure if this is possible in PHP namespaces. please help me

```
// folder structure
app
-- ModelsFolder // the models folder
---- ComponentsFolder // some traits
------ Traits::class
---- User::class
---- OtherModel::class
```

the Classes are only using the app folder as namespace

```
// User class
<?php
namespace App;
```

in my controllers i use the class as..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User; // import class
use App\OtherModel;
```

i wonder if this setup is possible, because it's giving me `FatalError` saying the `Class 'App\User' not found`.

i'm using psr-4 in my composer project.

Comment: Can you paste the autoload section of your composer.json here ?

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are from directory structure

User model

```
//User class

<?php 
namespace App\ModelsFolder;
```

In your controllers

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use App\ModelsFolder\User;  // import class 
use App\ModelsFolder\OtherModel;
```

Comment: No if you change the folder structure you need to change your namespaces accordingly, forgive my formatting it's not easy to format on mobile

Comment: If you'd like to use App\User you'd need to move your models up one directory level